# Excel formula to calculate taxes

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have the cost of a ticket without taxes on `N45`. I want to calculate 7% of that (take out comm. %), then add taxes from `P45`, but what formula do I use for that?

Say I have a ticket price for $100.00 (`N45`), I take 7% off of this, so now I have 93.00. To this I need to add say $30.00 (ticket taxes on `O45`), which brings me to a total of 123.00.

This 123.00 has to be in `Q45`.

What formula do I put in `Q45` so I get 123.00 there?

Comment: I fail to see what the OS version has to do with this. It is purely a 'how do I use excel' question.

Comment: I mean, say I have a ticket price for $100.00(N45), I take 7% off of this so now I have 93.00. To this I need to add say $30.00(ticket taxes on O45), which brings me to a # 123.00. This 123.00 has to be in Q45. Hence what formula to put in Q45 so I get 123.00 set up here

Answer (score 1):

`=(N45-(N45*0.07))+P45` probably, but it is not particularly clear exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: I mean, say I have a ticket price for $100.00(N45), I take 7% off of this so now I have 93.00. To this I need to add say $30.00(ticket taxes on O45), which brings me to a # 123.00. This 123.00 has to be in Q45. Hence what formula to put in Q45 so I get 123.00 set up here.

Comment: thz, but got some help from Microsoft.com, and put 2 and 2 together, and there you go!! I did =93%*N45+O45. DONE!!